# Does associativity imply commutativity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, binary-operations, associativity

I used to think that commutativity and associativity are two distinct properties. But recently, I started thinking of something which has troubled this idea:
$$(1+1)+1 = 1+ (1+1)\implies 2+1=1+2$$ Here using associativity of addition operation, we've shown commutativity.

In general, $$\underbrace{(1+1+\dots+1)}_{a \, 1\text{'s }}\ \ + \ \ \underbrace{(1+1+\dots+1)}_{b \, 1\text{'s }}=\underbrace{(1+1+\dots+1)}_{b \, 1\text{'s }}\ \ + \ \ \underbrace{(1+1+\dots+1)}_{a \, 1\text{'s }} \\ \implies a+b=b+a$$
For any natural $a,b$.
Hence using only associativity we prove commutativity. That this can be done, is disturbing me too much. Is this really correct? If yes, then are associativity and commutativity closely related? Or is it because of some other property of natural numbers? If yes, then can it be done for other structures as well?

Comment: @Omn But see  [Why ring addition is commutative.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/609402/242)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Well done - you've essentially rediscovered [free objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_object). In particular, what you've observed is that in the [semigroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup) freely generated by one element (call it $1$), addition happens to be commutative.

In other words: you've essentially explained why addition in $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}$ is commutative.

**But**, I wouldn't say that associativity implies commutativity *in general*. For instance, multiplication of $2 \times 2$ matrices provides a fundamental example of an associative operation that isn't commutative. Furthermore, the non-equivalence of associativity and commutativity is clear even if we stick to free algebras:

- in the semigroup freely generated by two elements (call them $A$ and $B$), commutativity fails in a big way. For example, $A + B \neq B+A$ in this context.
- in the commutative magma freely generated by one element (call it $1$), associativity fails in a big way. For example $(1+1)+(1+1) \neq ((1+1)+1)+1$ in this context.

Free algebras are pretty tricky, so don't feel discouraged if you don't 'get' them right away - nobody ever does. It can take a year or two before the idea truly 'sinks in,' and almost discovering them yourself will only help a little in this regard.

You may find [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1736287/i-dont-understand-what-a-free-group-is/1736701#1736701) question helpful to get you started.

Comment: [(for those who don't know what a semigroup is)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid).  [Here it is in "simple English"](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid)

Comment: [For more concrete examples of operations that are commutative but not associative](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160945/does-commutativity-imply-associativity)

Comment: @BenGrossmann, that "simple English definition" is very confusing and unclear. I recommend to future readers that they simply Google the proper definition.

Answer (score 21):

Clever observation. This is called a [cyclic group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_group) (or the generalized version, [free object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_object)). $ G $ is said to be cyclic, if there is some set $ s $, called the "generating element", such that

$$ G = \langle s \rangle = \{ n \in \mathbb{Z} : s^n \} = \{e, s, s^2, s^3, \ldots s^{-1}, s^{-2}, s^{-3}, \ldots \} $$

That is, all elements can be "generated" from a single element.

In this case $ s = 1 $, but let's forget that for a moment, and consider the general case:

1. Are cyclic objects always abelian?
2. Are all groups cyclic?

To 1., the answer is relatively simple: Yes. To verify this, we simply observe that $$ s^n s^m = \underbrace{sss\ldots s}_{n + m} = s^{n + m} = s^{m + n} = s^m s^n $$

Thus $ ab = ba $ in $ G $.

Now, for 2., the easiest way to prove that not all algebraic objects are cyclic, is to construct an object that isn't cyclic nor abelian. The simplest example is the group, $ G $, of bijective functions, $ \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $, under composition.

You can easily see that it is associative, at the same time it is relatively easy to verify that this is in fact not abelian (I will let you do that). Therefore it cannot be cyclic.

Another (more funky) way we can see that it is not cyclic is by Cantor's diagonal argument: Define $ \mathbb{R} $ as $ \{ f \in G : f(0) \} $. If $ G $ was cyclic, we would be able to enumerate the real numbers, by $ \mathbb{R} = \{ n \in \mathbb{Z} : s^n(0) \} $, which is not possible, as shown by the diagonal argument.

**A bonus**: Often people mistakenly believe that commutativity implies associativity, but that's in fact not true! Consider $ a * b = ab + 1 $. This is obviously commutative, but it isn't associative.

Comment: I am not sure whether you are using `\mathopen{<}s\mathclose{>}` $\mathopen{<}s\mathclose{>}$ on purpose. I guess $\langle s \rangle$ `\langle s \rangle` is used more often.

Comment: I normally write it that way.

Comment: I have changed it.

Comment: Is that intended to be $a*b=ab+1$ on the last line? A typo?

Comment: Yeah, good find.

Comment: Perhaps it should be made clear that a cyclic group does not have to be infinite.

Comment: This answer is good, but the functions $\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ do not form a group under composition. I suppose you meant either a monoid or bijections...

Answer (score 19):

> using only associativity we prove commutativity

Well, not really. You also used your knowledge that any natural number (but not zero or negative numbers!) can be expressed as a sum of `1`s. And you didn't prove "commutativity" in general; you proved "commutativity of addition (of natural numbers)", which you already knew to be true anyway.

A simple example of an operation that is associative but not commutative is "addition of strings" as defined in most programming languages — that is, string concatenation. Concatenation is associative:

```
("abc" + "def") + "ghi" = "abcdefghi"
"abc" + ("def" + "ghi") = "abcdefghi"
```

However, obviously, it's not commutative:

```
"abc" + "def" = "abcdef"
"def" + "abc" = "defabc"
```

And vice versa: [an example of an operation that is commutative but not associative](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/160950/121469) is $x\star y = xy+1$.

$
   (1 \star 2) = 3 \\
   (2 \star 1) = 3 \\
\text{but} \\
   (1 \star 2) \star 3 = 3 \star 3 = 10 \\
   1 \star (2 \star 3) = 1 \star 7 = 8
$

Comment: Your answer is correct, I guess just to be pedantic for the benefit of anyone who might be confused by your correct answer, in case one is only working with the concatenation of strings with _one_ letter (unary alphabet) then commutativity is equivalent to associativity (since this monoid is isomorphic to the free monoid with one generator/natural numbers + 0)

Comment: @Chill2Macht: First of all, you don't mean "strings of one letter" (e.g. `"a"` or `"x"`); you mean "strings from an alphabet of length 1" (e.g. `"a"`, `"aa"`, `"aaaaaaa"`). Secondly, you don't mean "commutativity *is equivalent to* associativity"; you mean that "concatenation in such a restricted case happens to be equivalent to addition; that is, it is commutative." There is a whole family of languages closed under concat where concat happens to be commutative; e.g. the language described by the regular expression `(cat)*`. The language `(a)*` just happens to be the most boring one. :)

Comment: Yes, basically (strings of a one-letter alphabet) -- what does "addition" of strings from an alphabet of length 1 mean? Also I think I do mean that, _in that restricted case_,  commutativity is equivalent to associativity, e.g. since 2+1 = 1+2 by commutativity, we have (1+1)+1=1+(1+1), i.e. associativity (admittedly I'm not sure if the example generalizes), and the OP gives the argument that associativity implies commutativity.

Comment: @Chill2Macht: The OP's example shows that *addition of natural numbers* is both commutative *and* associative; but it doesn't show anything about the *logical relationship* between those two properties in general. In your own example, the relationship between `"a"`, `"aa"`, `"aaa"`, and concatenation-of-strings is isomorphic to the relationship between `1`, `2`, `3`, and addition-of-natural-numbers; that's what I meant by "concatenation [in that case] is equivalent to addition".

Comment: You are right and that makes sense. I know it doesn't show anything about the logical relationship between the two properties _in general_; I am talking/asking about the logical relationship between the two properties _in that restricted case_, i.e. for the free semigroup generated by one element (obviously they aren't equivalent in general).

Comment: @Chill2Macht: There cannot be any "logical relationship" between two properties in a single special case; logical/causal relationships apply only in general. That is, I have shown `¬(C(x)→A(x))` by demonstrating that `∃y:C(y)∧¬A(y)`; and I've shown that `¬(A(x)→C(x))` by demonstrating that `∃z:A(z)∧¬C(z)`. You and the OP are strangely fascinated by the case of addition — `∃a:C(a)∧A(a)` — but this tells you nothing about the relationship between `A` and `C`; it's just a couple of uninteresting facts about `a`, joined by an `∧` sign.

Comment: The answer to the question "what is interesting" is really a matter of opinion/interpretation/taste, rather than of fact, so attempting to discuss it here might be unnecessarily confrontational. (Although I must admit to some surprise that you don't find the special case of the natural numbers to be interesting.) Anyway, I suppose that technically you are correct that "follows in a special case" is actually "implication following from the logical conjunction of two statements", although it does not seem to me that pointing this out either addresses the "spirit" or "substance" of my question.

Comment: Also, if we want to be unnecessarily pedantic without actually addressing the substance of what the other is saying, I could point out that "the case of addition", as you use it, is not well-defined. In any case, I should probably ask the question I have in mind as a separate question, rather than pestering you in the comments. I appreciate you taking the time to discuss this with me, even if the outcome was not as elucidating to me as I had hoped based on the high-quality of your answer to the question. https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Natural_Number_Addition_is_Commutative#Induction_Step_2

Answer (score 10):

If you have a group where every element is a power/multiple of a single element, then the group will be cyclic and hence Abelian. It looks like this is what you are doing. Recall that a group $G$ is called cyclic if
$$
G = \{g^n : n\in \mathbb{Z}\}.
$$
Then indeed you have that any two elements $h$ and $k$ can be written $h = g^n$ and $k = g^m$ for integers $n$ and $m$. Then $hk = g^ng^m = g^{n+m} = g^{m+n} = g^mg^n = kh$.

Note, specifically, that the integers (under addition) is a cyclic group.

But, no, associativity does not imply commutativity. There are many examples. Take any non-Abelian group: $n\times n$ matrices over (most) rings, permutation groups, ...

Comment: It's not clear how "$ n\times n$ matrices over (most) rings" provides an example of a nonabelian group. (The set of nonsingular $2\times2$ matrices over a field does constitute a nonabelian group under multiplication, however.)

Answer (score 9):

A standard example of associative non-commutative structure are square matrices $M_{n\times n}(\Bbb C)$ with respect to a usual matrix product.

One can easily build commutative non-associative structures, like the "rock-paper-scissors", where the binary operation yields the winner: $$(p,p)\to p,\quad (p,r)\to p,\quad (p,s)\to s,\quad etc.$$

Hence these properties are not related in general, yet, for natural numbers, as other members of the community said, you are in luck.

Answer (score 7):

The easiest counter-example that I can think of is function composition. We know that $f \circ(g \circ h) = (f \circ g) \circ h$ but it is not necessarily true that $f \circ g = g \circ f$.

As someone else pointed out, if that was true, then there wouldn't be any non abelian groups.

Answer (score 5):

Consider an $\operatorname L$ operator defined as 'take the left': $$a \operatorname L b = a$$
For any three $a,b,c$:
$$(a \operatorname L b) \operatorname L c = a \operatorname L c = a = a \operatorname L b = a \operatorname L (b \operatorname L c)$$
but
$$a \operatorname L b = a \ne b = b \operatorname L a$$
unless $a=b$.