# Is the free associative unital algebra generated by one element isomorphic to the polynomial algebra in one variable?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

The [free associative algebra generated by one element/indeterminate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_algebra) is "the same thing as" the tensor algebra of a one-dimensional vector space, as far as I understand [(1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_algebra#Non-commutative_polynomials)[(2)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_object#General_case_2)[(3)](http://math.mit.edu/~dav/freeassoc.pdf)[(4)](http://www.planetmath.org/freeassociativealgebra)[(5)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_algebra#Contrast_with_Polynomials).

I'm not sure how much the choice of coefficients matters for the question; if it does matter, assume for the sake of simplicity that the coefficients are real numbers, $\mathbb{R}$.

I think this follows from the fact that the [free semigroup generated by one element is commutative](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1826030/327486) (and thus so is the free monoid generated by one element as well as [the free group generated by one element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_group#Examples)). I.e., for the same reason the above facts are true, one can't really distinguish $X \otimes X \otimes X$ and $X^3$ in some sense (since there is only one indeterminate/unknown/variable, as long as we have associativity, expressions of the same length are indistinguishable, which implies commutativity).

I don't have a formal proof in mind and am not requesting a formal proof, since I am already fairly convinced that this is true, but would nevertheless appreciate a sanity check.

Comment: "the tensor algebra in one variable" doesn't really make sense, I think you mean "the tensor algebra of a one-dimensional vector space". Otherwise, I agree. Choice of coefficients does not matter, as long as they match up.

Comment: @Joppy I agree, that makes more sense, I edited my post. Thank you for the confirmation